# What do the values recorded by the default Veins's example represent?

Tags: omnet++, veins

The example comes with the Veins packet for OMNET++ record values, such as

- generatedBSM
- generatedWSA
- generatedWSM
- receivedBSM
- receivedWSA
- receivedWSM
- totalRXTXLostPackets
- TotalSentPackets
- totalSNIRLostPackets
- TotalLostPackets

I understand the first six values. However, the summation of (generatedBSM, generatedWSA, and generatedWSM) do not equal the TotalSentPackets!

Moreover, what is the difference between the totalRXTXLostPackets and the totalSNIRLostPackets?